# 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine giving exception on client

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, excel, oledb

I am getting error while reading excel file with MVC website on client machine

'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine

Its perfectly working with localhost

suggest me something

Comment: See this: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vstsdb/thread/1d5c04c7-157f-4955-a14b-41d912d50a64

Comment: I have already checked this out but problem is different

Comment: Could you edit your question with the troubleshooting you've tried so far? It might help others looking at the question.

Answer (score 0):

> “The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine”

***Fix:***
Install the **[2007 Office System Driver: Data Connectivity Components](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=23734)**

For more information, see [SQL SERVER – FIX – Export Error – ‘Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0’ provider is not registered on the local machine](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2015/06/24/sql-server-fix-export-error-microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine/)