# OraOledb.oracle provider is not registered on the local machine(Blueprism)

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oledb, blueprism

I am connecting Oracle DB through Blue prism. But I got the below error

> OraOledb.oracle provider is not registered on the local machine

I installed the OLEDB (64 Bit) from oracle website. Then the OLEDB got listed in the provider list also. But still, I am facing the error.

Comment: Is your Blue prism also 64 bit?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OraOLEDB.Oracle provider is not registered on the local machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12903366/oraoledb-oracle-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine)

Comment: yes Wernfried it is 64Bit .

Comment: @JamalMohamed Check my answer on **['Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine giving exception on client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16238411/microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine-givin/61702777#61702777)**.